# Unity Google Play Games IsConnectedToRoom Check

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, real-time, google-play-games, multiplayer

I'm having trouble to check if a participant is still connected to a room.

I wrote this:

```
bool status=GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.MultiplayerParticipant.AutomatchingSentinel().IsConnectedToRoom();

if (status = true) 
{
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "participant is connected";
}

if (status = false) 
{
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "participant left";
}`
```

When players are connected, "participant is connected" is displayed.

But when a player press the home button, and go back to the screen, the participant had OnPeersDisconnected called and leave the room. But for the actual player, "participant is connected" is still displayed.

How can i know when the IsConnectedToRoom() is false?

Answer (score 0):

This may still depend on how implementation is going to be. According to the [document](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#querying_a_participants_status):

> Make sure to construct your game logic carefully to take each participant's status and connectedness into account. For example, to determine if all racers have crossed the finish line, your game should only consider the participants who are connected; some may have left the room or never have accepted the invitation.

#### Detecting when a player is disconnected

> Your player might be disconnected from the room due to network connectivity or server issues. To be notified when a player is disconnected from the room, implement the **`OnConnectedSetChanged`** method.

```
virtual void OnConnectedSetChanged(RealTimeRoom const &room) {
  // Check the room's participants to see who connected/disconnected.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i didn't understand how to use that, but i follow another path. My issue comes when the user go to home screen, or to another app. And when the user go back to the game, he already left the room, but the game is still running even if the other participant left too (he had the LeaveRoom callback). So i decide to use 'OnApplicationPause()' because the app is paused, and i run my code through that.